# Calculate mean of rows when matching separate dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Given a data frame with index and data columns like so:

```
AIndex <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
AData  <- c(3,5,6,7,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
DF <- data.frame(AIndex,AData)
```

And given a second data frame with some overlap in the index like so:

```
BIndex <- c(1,4,8,11,13)
BData  <- c(3,5,7,6,5)
DF2 <- data.frame(BIndex,BData)
```

My goal is to be able to find where the Index in A and the Index in B match up in the A data frame, and then calculate the mean of that row in A + 2 rows.

For example, the first time A and B match up in A is row# 1. So I would want to find the corresponding data point in A (3) and the next two data points (5 and 6). So the mean would be 4.6

The final result would be a new data frame that looked like this:

```
Index Data
1     4.6
4      4
8      3
11     6
13     8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. The first will step usually involves finding where the elements match:

```
mats = match(DF2$BIndex, DF$AIndex)
```

To find the means, just add up the relevant values

```
(AData[mats] + AData[mats+1] + AData[mats+2])/3
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to R and this community. I try to follow @csgillespie's step. the result turns out to be this:

```
> DF2 <- data.frame(BIndex, BData)  
> newInd <- merge(dat, DF2, by.x="AIndex", by.y="BIndex", all.y=T)  
> newInd$newCM <- (AData[mats] + AData[mats+1] + AData[mats+2]) / 3
> newInd

  AIndex AData BData    newCM  
1      1     3     3 4.666667  
2      4     7     5 4.000000  
3      8     2     7 3.000000  
4     11     5     6 6.000000  
5     13     7     5 8.000000
```

Three thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This may well solve the problem, but please also provide an explanation. Many new users come to SO and explanation with your code helps them to learn how to adapt the code to solve their problem. In this case, for example, you could say that the important command is `merge` to identify the matching entries.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. @JenB My english skills are just fair but let me try. Merge, as its own name, used to merge the two dataframes, dat and DF2, by identification key, AIndex in dat (or x in the attribute) and AIndex in DF2 (or y of by.y). all.y=T indicates type of merge, seems to be right join in MySql, includes all rows in DF2$BIndex (or y) but some rows in dat$AIndex.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF2)[,mean(DF[BIndex:(BIndex+2),'AData']),BIndex]
#   BIndex       V1
#1:      1 4.666667
#2:      4 4.000000
#3:      8 3.000000
#4:     11 6.000000
#5:     13 8.000000
```